# Erro estranho na tela, debug não mostra nda

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em Webform, esta dando algum erro, que ao debugar no Visual Studio (f5) ele não acusa nenhum erro, porém quando sai o resultado na tela seria como um erro interno(500)
Não tem nenhum AJAX ou algo do tipo é apenas uma página 'teóricamente simples'

**Dúvida:**

Existe alguma maneira melhor de debugar? existe algum erro que faz não exibir o erro na tela?

web.config

```
 <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
```

Basicamente tenho uma página
**wizard.aspx**

```
otimizacao_pontos otim = new otimizacao_pontos();
otim .TotalPontos();
EntidadeWizard iPontos = new EntidadeWizard();
iPontos = (EntidadeWizard)Session["iPontos"];
```

**a classe otimizacao_pontos**

```
        public void TotalPontos()
        {
            EntidadeWizard iPontos = new EntidadeWizard();

/// monte de códigos 
HttpContext.Current.Session["iPontos"] = iPontos;
```

}

**e a entidade:**

```
    public class EntidadeWizard
    {
        private int TotalImoveis = 0;

        public int TotalImoveis1
        {
            get { return TotalImoveis; }
            set { TotalImoveis = value; }
        }

        public int TotalImoveisFOTO { get; set; }
        public int TotalDestaque { get; set; }

        public double _E1_point { get; set; }
        public double _E2_point { get; set; }
        public double _E3_point { get; set; }
        public double _E4_point { get; set; }

        public double _E5_point { get; set; }
        public bool _E5_MailFull = false;
        public bool _E5_MailDomain = false;
        private bool _E5_Erro = false;

        public bool E5_Erro
        {
            get { return _E5_Erro; }
            set { _E5_Erro = value; }
        }

        public double _E6_point { get; set; }
        public bool _E6_Atualizado = false;

        public double _E7_point { get; set; }

        public double E7_point_Mega { get; set; }

        public double _E7_point_Mercado { get; set; }
        public double _E7_point_USA { get; set; }
        public double _E7_point_Trovit { get; set; }
        public double _E7_point_Ibiubi { get; set; }
        public double _E7_point_Fisgo { get; set; }
        public double _E7_point_Mitula { get; set; }
        public double _E7_point_Imohoo { get; set; }
        public double _E7_point_OLX { get; set; }
        public double _E7_point_Nuroa { get; set; }
        public double _E7_point_Divendo { get; set; }
        public double _E8_point { get; set; }
        private bool _E8_Correto = false;

        public bool E8_Correto
        {
            get { return _E8_Correto; }
            set { _E8_Correto = value; }
        }
        public double _E9_point { get; set; }
        public double _E9_percent { get; set; }
        public double _E10_point { get; set; }
        public double _E11_point { get; set; }
        public int _E11_Dias { get; set; }

        public double _E12_point { get; set; }
        public double _E12_percent { get; set; }

        public string _urlLogotipo { get; set; }


        private double _vTOTALInterno { get; set; }

        public double _vTOTAL
        {
            get { return _vTOTALInterno; }
            set { _vTOTALInterno = value; }
        }

        public string textMail { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Básicamente a classe joga os valores para dentro da Session e depois faço unboxing e recupero os valores, ou deveria. Estou verificando a entidade se tem algum bug..mas não vejo.

Comment: Poderia postar algum trecho do código/página?

Comment: o código é tão grande, vou editar a pergunta para melhorar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri o erro.

faltou na entidade colocar

```
[Serializable]
```

Porém o mais estranho é que acredito que esse erro deveria ser algo do tipo:

```
Não foi possível seriarializar ou o objeto não é serializável
```

E não um erro como aqueles.

Comment: Estava com o mesmo problema... Colocando o [Serializable], funcionou. Obrigado.

Comment: da +1 na resposta @RafaelDoCantoCardoso se ela te ajudou, abs